# Angular Navigating to Secondary Route while Preserving Primary Route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I would like to navigate to a secondary route called modal without explicitly stating the primary route.

I've tried this in the component class:

```
onclick(){
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { foo: 'modal' } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

The above code seems to work.  However, it navigates to `/first(foo:modal)` for a split second then it navigates to the root `/`.

What am I doing wrong?

It would be nice to do something like:

```
<a href="#" routerLink="/*(foo:modal)">Open Modal</a>
```

So that it matches any primary route.... Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set only the secondary segment by specifying the outlet `{ oultletName: url}`

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { modal: 'edit/20']}}]">Edit</a>   
router.navigate([{outlets: { modal: 'edit/20'}}]);
```

or multiple segments:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'products', modal: 'edit/20']}}]">Edit</a> 
router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: 'products', modal: 'edit/20'}}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was `href="#"` on the achor tag that was causing the immediate redirect. Removing it resolved the issue.

To navigate to a secondary route regardless of the primary route:

```
<a routerLink="one" >Home</a>
<a routerLink="two" >Admin</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { foo: 'modal' } }]">open</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { foo: null } }]">close</a>
```

And if you want to navigate imperatively:

```
<a (click)="open()">Open</a>
<a (click)="close()">Close</a>

open() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { foo: 'modal' } }]);
}
close() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { foo: null } }]);
}
```

Comment: Navigating imperatively only works if the route is a root. If the route is a child, specify the entire route including the part of the primary up to the outlet or pass the ActivatedRoute as the NavigationExtras.relativeTo.

Comment: Why would you make your outlet modal a child route?

Comment: That's a good question. First, it might have to be because it is part of a lazy loaded module. Second, the outlet may require a resource resolved by a parent primary route.

Comment: Depends on how you design the modal. Regardless of whether it’s lazy loaded or not, you can (and probably should) set it up at a global level. If it needs resources resolved via a parent route - again that’s a design choice

Comment: Yes, it is a design decision which was good for my use case. Your answer is correct. I was just providing extra information in case someone else needed it as well.