# How can I use multiple <router-outlet> in my angular4 project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

How can I use multiple `<router-outlet>` in my angular4 project?

When I go to `/docs` path -> WelcomeComponent to be displayed in the outlet where `name = welcome`
and all other routes to be displayed in the default outlet.

## `app.routing.ts file`

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module'
import { WelcomeComponent } from '../welcome/welcome.component';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'docs', component: WelcomeComponent, outlet: 'welcome'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/getSerials/customerId/1027356' }
]

export const AppRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
  useHash: true,
  enableTracing: true
})
```

## `app.component.html`

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="column-sm-12">
        <br/><br/><br/>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div>
        <router-outlet name="welcome"></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

## Updated question

On page load, I am on `localhost:4200/#/abcd`

I have an anchor tag having `(click)= "changeRoute()"` event. where

```
changeRoute() {
this.route.navigate([{ outlets: { welcome: ['welcome']}}])
}
```

but when I click anchortag which calls changeRounte() function the current url changes to `localhost:4200/#/abcd(welcome:welcome)` and the welcomeComponent is never loaded.

Comment: What is the issue with your current implementation ?

Comment: @Zze - It isn't working when I go to `/docs` nothing is coming up, getting this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'docs'

Comment: Can you please add the code that is causing the error? like the routerLink or whatever you are using which prompts the error.

Comment: My assumption is that your trying to invoke the route incorrectly as what you have supplied looks fine to me.

Comment: For testing, I am manually changing the URL. like: localhost:4200/#/docs



Ideally, when u  go to `/docs` it should render the HTML for `WelcomeComponent` in <router-outlet name="welcome"></router-outlet>

Comment: This is a working example I have tried replicating what I am trying to achieve. You can make changes to this and send me back the URL if that works Thanks,

everything is inside `app` folder. For testing try going to `\test` or `\hello` path.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxlben

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> `localhost:4200/docs` Ideally, when u go to `/docs` it should render the HTML for `WelcomeComponent` in `<router-outlet name="welcome"></router-outlet>`

I think this is a misunderstanding of how you use named router-outlets. From the [spec](https://angular.io/guide/router):

> Named outlets are the targets of **secondary routes**.
>
> Secondary routes look like primary routes and you configure them the
>   same way. They differ in a few key respects:
>
> They are independent of each other. 
>   
> **They work in combination with other routes.** 
>   
> They are displayed in named outlets.

See at the moment, you are trying to navigate to `/docs`, however this is not a primary route. As far as I am aware, you are [not able to navigate to a secondary route via a url change.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395788/angular-navigating-to-secondary-route-while-preserving-primary-route)

---

What you need to do is open a primary route, and then trigger the opening of your secondary route.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, outlet: 'welcome'}, // secondary
  { path: 'docs', component: DocsComponent}, // primary
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/getSerials/customerId/1027356' }
]
```

Now what will happen is that `localhost:4200/docs` will render `DocsComponent` within the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Then from within your `app.component.ts` you can do something like:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { welcome: ['welcome'] }}]);
}
```

Here we are saying to find the `<router-outlet>` with `name='welcome'` and then inject the component which matches the route `['welcome']` ... i.e our secondary route defined above.

So your rendered html will look something like...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-sm-12">
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <router-outlet><!-- DocsComponent content --></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <router-outlet name="welcome"><!-- WelcomeComponent content --></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh1uwm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zze, using the above solution I am not getting errors anymore. But the issue is I am trying to use 
`this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { welcome: [welcome'] }}]);` on a click event instead on ngOnInit. when I do so it is appending the welcome route to existing URL and failing to load welcomeComponent. 

Let me know if u have any questions or need more explanation of the problem Thanks

Comment: @ArjunPawar You should just be able to put that line into the event handler!  `<button (click)="loadWelcomeRoute()"> ... ` and then call the above from the function. If that is what you already have and it is erroring, then can you please update your question with that event code.

Comment: Please see the working example in the update to the post @ArjunPawar. Note the route load when you click the words: "hello test!"

Comment: when u click on "hello test!" the route loads along with `test.component`. I just want the child route to be present. basically when u click on "hello test!" u should see only HTML pertaining to hello component.

Comment: Literally your question states: *"WelcomeComponent to be displayed in the outlet where name = welcome and **all other routes to be displayed in the default outlet.**"* @ArjunPawar . Now you're telling me you don't want this and just want normal routing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Zze, I am not looking for normal routing instead I wanted to have multiple <router-outlets> so that I can load respective routes in respective outlets. instead of all the routes being loading on the same outlet based on the path.

Comment: Anyways, I found a different approach, Your answers were quite helpful though. Thank you much :)

Comment: @ArjunPawar You should post it as the accepted answer then.